# CSS center the image horizontally and vertically in img tag

Tags: html, css

I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow. None works for my case. I am wondering if I can still center the image within my html structure limitation?

Here is my CSS and HTML.

```
<div class="test">  
    <img src="http://test.com/test.jpg" />
    This is the test text here..This is the test text here.This is the test text here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    top:auto;
    left: auto;
    float: right;
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is my test case in http://jsfiddle.net/QBK2y/3/

Comment: You obvisouly set `float:right` for your image, looks like you mean center it **vertically**?

Comment: Are you trying to center the image (and put the text below it), or treat te image and text as a block, which is centered inside the div?

Comment: The image size is reduced. But, it still have max-width and max-height and they are treated as a placeholder. I want to center within max width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a div wrapping around the img tag as follows. Unfortunately, the HTML structure limitation cannot be satisfied. This is no way to center the image without a placeholder.

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="placeholder">
         <img src="http://test.com/test.jpg" />
    </div>
    This is the test text here..This is the test text here.This is the test text here.
</div>
```

Then, the new css should be.

```
div.test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

div.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    top:auto;
    left: auto;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC; //border is not necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to center the image horizontally all you need is this:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to center align horizontally and vertically an element in an element that has a height set..

```
.test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    position:relative;
}

.test img {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0;
  left:0
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

---

Edit: [Forked your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/669sW/](http://jsfiddle.net/669sW/)

---

Now what to do with that text  ...